# Adding popups in spring

Tags: spring

I am writing a code to login from spring. In it I need to show error messages in a popup and redirect to certain page. I'm using a method but it only gives the error on a new page.

Here is the code.

```java
modelAndView.addObject("message", "Wrong Password!!");
modelAndView.setViewName("error");
```

I need to show this message in a popup and when I click "OK", it needs to redirect to another page. How can I do it?

Comment: What are you using as template engine? Thymeleaf?

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap.

Comment: Bootstrap is a CSS framework, not the template engine. Spring needs a template engine in order to render the html page